# NSTimer not firing propery

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have set up a timer class to firer when the viewDidLoad(). I want to have a timer on multiple view controllers thoughout the app. If you have a better solution to a accurate timer on multiple views please suggest.

Viewcontroller -> One of the views that needs a timer

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

    func setupTimer() {

        // Setupt the timer, this will call the timerFired method every second
        var timer = NSTimer(
            timeInterval: 1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(TestTimer.timerFired()),//<- Error Code
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
         }
```

The Error Code: Use of instance member 'timerFired' on type 'TestTimer',did you mean to use a value of type 'TestTimer' instead?

Timer Class -> Checks start date compared to current date/time for a accurate timer

```
 class TestTimer: NSTimer {

var timer   = NSTimer()
// Converter changes String into NSDate
var startDate = converter("Tue, 26 Apr 2016 09:01:00 MDT")
// Function to be fired
func timerFired() {

    let now = NSDate()
    let difference = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(self.startDate)


    // Format the difference for display
    // For example, minutes & seconds
    let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(difference)
    print(difference)

 }
 }
```

Comment: so what are you actually trying to do when the timer fires? presumably not just print...

Comment: Remove the `()` from the end of your `timerFired` in the `#selector`. Although you should note that this still won't work, as `self` in that context refers to the view controller, not the timer. You'll have to re-think your logic.

Comment: If you can tell us why you need to get the actual time difference between timer invocations for the sake accuracy, we may be able to help you find a solution. I suspect that you don't even want to be using `NSTimer` here, as they're not at all designed for accuracy.

Comment: I want to update a label with the difference value

Comment: @originaluser2 I know that a NSTimer isn't perfect accurate so I'm having it check the difference between the start time and now. What is the best way of having an accurate timer?

Comment: @Ring-Jarvi Depends what you're trying to do. If you're doing constant drawing updates, then you should use a `CADisplayLink` in order to synchronise drawing the screen refresh rate. You may want to look into using a `dispatch_source` in order to get a more accurate version of an `NSTimer`. Although, now that I've seen your timer is only firing once a second, I actually think your approach is correct – although you shouldn't subclass `NSTimer`. Just create a wrapper class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is pretty obscure. What it's trying to tell you is you should remove the `()` from the end of your `timerFired` in the `#selector`.

```
var timer = NSTimer(
    timeInterval: 1.0,
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(TestTimer.timerFired),
    userInfo: nil,
    repeats: true)
```

However, this isn't going to make your code how you want it to work – as `self` in the timer declaration refers to the view controller, not the timer. I would recommend you create a wrapper class for `NSTimer`, along with a delegate pattern in order to achieve what you want.

You should note that [the documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) that you shouldn't attempt to subclass `NSTimer`, so you could do something like this instead:

```
// the protocol that defines the timerDidFire callback method
protocol TimerDelegate:class {
    func timerDidFire(cumulativeTime:NSTimeInterval)
}

// your timer wrapper class
class TimerWrapper {

    // the underlying timer object
    weak private var _timer:NSTimer?

    // the start date of when the timer first started
    private var _startDate = NSDate()

    // the delegate used to implement the timerDidFire callback method
    weak var delegate:TimerDelegate?

    // start the timer with a given firing interval – which could be a property
    func startTimer(interval:NSTimeInterval) {

        // if timer already exists, make sure to stop it before starting another one
        if _timer != nil {
            stopTimer()
        }

        // reset start date and start new timer
        _startDate = NSDate()
        _timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval,
                                                        target: self,
                                                        selector: #selector(timerDidFire),
                                                        userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    // invalidate & deallocate the timer,
    // make sure to call this when you're done with the timer
    func stopTimer() {
        _timer?.invalidate()
        _timer = nil
    }

    // make sure to stop the timer when the wrapper gets deallocated
    deinit {
        stopTimer()
    }

    // called when the timer fires
    @objc func timerDidFire() {

        // get the change in time, from when the timer first fired to now
        let deltaTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(_startDate)

        // do something with delta time

        // invoke the callback method
        delegate?.timerDidFire(deltaTime)
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
// your view controller class – make sure it conforms to the TimerDelegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, TimerDelegate {

    // an instance of the timer wrapper class
    let timer = TimerWrapper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set the timer delegate and start the timer – delegate should be set in viewDidLoad,
        // timer can be started whenever you need it to be started.
        timer.delegate = self
        timer.startTimer(1)
    }

    func timerDidFire(cumulativeTime: NSTimeInterval) {

        // do something with the total time

        let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
        let text = dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(cumulativeTime)
        label.text = text
    }
}
```

As far as the appropriateness of using an `NSTimer` here goes, as you're only using a time interval of 1 second, an `NSTimer` is suitable. By taking the time interval over the total timer duration, you can average out any small firing inaccuracies.

Comment: I appreciate your work on this, I've never used a wrapper before. I believe I understand the class TimerWrapper section of code but I'm having problems implementing it. Where would I use this code? viewDidLoad? @originaluser2

Comment: "timer.delegate = self" is what i'm having the most problems with, this makes sense but I'm struggling to get it to work in playground or my project

Comment: @Ring-Jarvi I have fleshed out my answer with extra context on its usage and comments – hopefully that clears up any problems you're having with it :)

Comment: Amazing job dumbing this down! Perfect!

Comment: @Ring-Jarvi Happy to help :)

Comment: `_timer` could be `weak` because `NSTimer` is retaining its target. I would also invalidate the timer from `dealloc`, too but those are only minor points.

Comment: @Sulthan True, I did initially consider that when writing it – although because the timer retains its target (and the run-loop retains the timer), I believe the only way to break that is to invalidate the timer, and doing that in this case also sets the timer to `nil`, which should break any retain cycles. And because of this, `deinit` will never actually be called until the timer is invalidated in the first place. Although I will still edit my answer to include your proposed changes, just to make the relationship between timer and wrapper clearer – thanks for raising the point!

Comment: @originaluser2 You are right with the `deinit` of course. I just remembered I used `CFRunLoopTimer` once instead just to break the retaining behavior.

Comment: @Sulthan Ah okay interesting, I've never actually played around with `CFRunLoopTimer` – I'll certainly have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how a timer is initialized

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0 , target: self, selector: #selector(TestTimer.timerFired()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```